# R / chron - data.frame tag by time-range

Tags: r, datetime, chron

First question to stackoverflow so apologies if I don't follow etiquette...

I have a table `df` similar to the following:

```
subject_id date_time
1          1999-10-20 19:08:00
2          1983-03-16 00:28:14
....
```

I'm trying to add further columns to flag the day of the event (which I've figured out using `wday`) but I need a further flag for whether the event was in working hours (i.e. between 0800 and 1700).  So far I can extract the hour from date_time using

```
df$hour = as.numeric(format(df$date_time, "%H"))
```

but I'm struggling to add a column to the end of `df` which would be conditional `0` (in hours) or `1` based on `df$hour`. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using `chron`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(chron)
df <- df%>% mutate(Hour = hours(date_time), Value = ifelse((Hour > 7 & Hour < 18), 0, 1))
```